# Show rooms in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, nodes

I am new to socket.io and would like to know how to list the rooms.

I create the rooms with this code:

```
socket.on('room', (data) => {
      console.log(data);

      socket.join(data.user);
      io.sockets.to(data.user).emit('server', datos);
    });
```

Help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Socket.IO version 1.x or 2.x, use:

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms
```

Bellow version 1, use:

```
io.sockets.manager.rooms
```

With your code:

```
socket.on('room', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  socket.join(data.user);

  let datos = io.sockets.adapter.rooms;
  console.log(datos);

  io.sockets.to(data.user).emit('server', datos);
});
```

Also, check out the [Socket.IO emit cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/).